# get path from other ZF2 module

Tags: zend-framework2

Hiho,
I actually writing a module for an bbcode viewhelper for ZF2.
For this I use Decoda.
It works fine but I don't get the Path to the emoticons.
I defined it in my Class as following:

```
    public function __invoke($request)
{
    $bbcode = new Decoda($request);
    $bbcode->defaults();
    $bbcode->addFilter(new \Decoda\Filter\ImageFilter());
    $bbcode->addHook(new \Decoda\Hook\EmoticonHook(array('path' => __DIR__.'/emoticons/')));
    return $bbcode->parse();
}
```

This sets the path to my own Module into the folder emoticons.
But to keep it clear i don't want to copy the emoticons folder from the Decodamodule to
my one.
Does any one has an idea how to get the path to the Decoda Module?

Answer (score 0):

The **__*DIR*__** constant points to the folder of your helper file.

And i guess 'emoticons' folder should be somewhere in the public folder.

Comment: the same with ROOT_PATH.'images/emoticons'.

Comment: sorry edit time was over.  The same with ROOT_PATH.'images/emoticons'. I can call it with my browser and get the folder with the images shown but firebug says me that the requestet url couldn't be loaded. The Problem is that the original emoticons folder is located in /vendor/mjohnson/decoda/emoticons and I wouldn't copy the folder to an other place (memory usage).